# cordova 2.1 cdvviewcontroller.h missing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

I have just installed the new PhoneGap 2.1.0 and followed all of the steps to start a project exactly and it seemed to work except that when I try to run it on the iPhone 6 simulator I get an error that says Cordova/CDVViewController.h is missing. I am using XCode 4.5 on a MacBook Pro running Lion. I have seen that a lot of people have had this error but no solutions have been provided. Can anyone help with this? Also, I uninstalled PhoneGap 2.0 before installing the new PhoneGap.

Thanks.

Comment: One more thing that I think that I should add, the Cordovalib.xcodeproj is red.

Comment: I have found the solution to my own question. There is a CordovaLib folder in the iOS folder of the PhoneGap 2.1.0 download. It had not been moved to where the other files were unpacked. After I put it there, the project compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to completely remove PhoneGap 2.0 before you install PhoneGap 2.1. What I did was to install 2.1 and then try to create a project. After it didn't work, I used the 2.0 uninstall program. That removed my CordovaLib folder even though I unpacked it in the 2.1 folder. I looked in the lib/ios folder of the PhoneGap 2.1 download and copied the CordovaLib folder to where I had put the other files from the iOS folder and that took care of it. I also could have just replaced the entire ios folder that I had unpacked.

I am using XCode 4.5 and I am targeting iOS 6 so there was an additional step that I had to do to make it run in the simulator. I had to click on CordovaLib.xcodeproj in the project navigator in Xcode and then changed the value in Build Active Architecture Only to YES. That completed my solution.

Does that help you ac360?